# Oracle : reconnect to database link if disconnected

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle stored procedure that queries data through database link, sometimes it takes a while, and got Oracle error as below:

```
ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged of
```

Is there any way to reconnect the database link if it got disconnected?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `SYSDBA` access you can give a try with increasing the `CONNECT_TIME`  parameter in `DEFAULT` profile( You can also create your own profile and do the following. I am considering only default profile). See below steps:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> alter profile default
  2  limit connect_time 10 --10 refers to 10 minutes
  3  /

Profile altered.
```

Set `RESOURCE_LIMIT` to `TRUE` so that limits would be `enforced`:

```
SQL> alter system set resource_limit = true
  2  /

System altered.

SQL>
```

Then give `DEFAULT` profile to the `user`(Like Scott) you are using to connect Oracle Session.

```
SQL> alter user SCOTT profile DEFAULT;

User altered.

SQL> grant create session to SCOTT
  2  /

Grant succeeded.
```

Comment: I am not a DBA, is there anyway I can do from the application level?

Comment: Then you might need to create your own profile. I used SYSDBA user to use DEFAULT one. Give a try and see if that works

Comment: sad to say, i have no privilege to create my own profile :(

Comment: may be you can reach to your DBA and discuss your case with him.

Comment: Actually, I did contacted our DBA, but they mentioned that they could not increase the connect_time because that is the standard configuration. So I am looking for options to reconnect from the application side once disconnected.

Comment: Well i dont see any other way except manually reconnecting everytime or might be some automated script which do not allow the session to timeout. Not sure though. Good luck.